# When Pokémon hatch from their egg, are they full size?

Tags: pokemon

If someone were to have a Chansey egg (for example), would it be around 3" tall (as tall as Chansey)? Would it weigh as much? Would a full-sized Chansey hatch from the egg, or would it be smaller than normal and grow to full size?

Comment: Chansey's eggs will hatch into Happiny, FWIW.

Comment: @CreationEdge I haven't seen the anime in a really long time, is that how it works there? I know in the games you can get Chansey eggs (Happinys need to be bred with a special item, similar to Pichus).

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. BTW, is your question about the games, or the show?

Comment: @CreationEdge That's a good question, honestly. I'm trying to write a fanfiction and just wanted some context. I guess I have a bit of creative license so I can use stuff from both.

Comment: [There's a comic about this very question!](http://www.rarecandytreatment.com/comics/1012869/miracle-of-life/#cpage)

Comment: @CreationEdge: Only if one of the parents held a Luck Incense. With no incense, you get a Chansey.

Comment: @Thunderforge sorry about that! I assumed the other guy was right. Also, I'm more used to StackOverflow where all the answers flow in during the first 5 minutes or so. I've accepted your answer because it's better (more detailed, more supporting evidence) and correct.

Comment: Do all Pokemon hatch from eggs? Even the ones that are clearly mammals? Madness!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### In the animé, baby Pokémon are not full size

All of the Pokémon that have been shown to hatch from eggs in the animé are small Pokémon that are only slightly larger than the eggs they were in (e.g. Misty's Togepi, Ash's Phanpy, May's Eevee). So that is not an indicator in itself. However, we have seen baby Pokémon who presumably hatched from eggs, yet are much smaller than their adult counterparts.

For instance, the special *Mewtwo Returns* shows baby Rhydon and Nidoqueen who are referred to as babies, and their parents are shown to be full sized:

[image]

It's small, but you can see the babies next to their parents in the picture below:

[image]

And yes, those are baby Nidoqueen, despite it being a Stage 3, stone-based evolution. It's not clear if that's a production mistake, or if something happened to make them like that (maybe Mewtwo's clone Pokémon have genetic modifications?).

We also see evidence of aging. Ash's Lapras was a child of its species, thus smaller than an adult Lapras. Ash released it when it was reunited with the school of Lapras including its larger mother. When Ash was reunited with his Lapras, it was larger and looked more like an adult Lapras (animated picture below):

[image]

For fun, here is what it would look like if baby Pokémon *did not* grow from smaller versions and instead hatched at full size:

[image]
(Comic from [Rare Candy Treatment](http://www.rarecandytreatment.com/comics/1012869/miracle-of-life/#cpage))

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the Pokemon, but most Pokemon hatch at full size according to the pokedex. We can assume the eggs themselves are proportionally large. Some Pokemon do have, young or baby versions which are smaller sized then their adult versions.

> According to a girl in Solaceon Town, where one of many Pokémon Day Cares are located, no one has ever seen a Pokémon lay an Egg, and thus, it is not confirmed that this is how they appear. According to a Monsieur in Coumarine City, Eggs are not actually eggs and are more like "cradles". [LINK](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Egg)

this makes it appear that the eggs themselves are more like incubators, taking born pokemon and getting them full sized.

> later Eggs are shown to flash white before hatching, then to glow white and transform into the Pokémon they contain, slightly in the same way as evolving. [link2](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Egg#In_the_anime)

Similar to pokemon evolution, in which size can drastically change, is appears eggs can be smaller to still contain larger pokemon.

As user867 states pokemon only have weight and length, and some descriptions offer various sizes for full grown pokemon. so their is variation to consider.

Comment: There's only one length and weight listed for each Pokédex entry - yet there are Pokédex entries that describe Pokémon changing in size due to growth, shedding, and other reasons. I strongly suspect, therefore, that the lengths and weights in the Pokedex are observed averages, rather than absolute values which no member of the species ever deviates from. You may well be right about them being born full sized, but the lengths and weights in the Pokedex aren't evidence of that.

Comment: @user867 good point there is variation ill update shortly

Comment: If Pokémon eggs are proportionally sized and weighted to their full versions, how are Lapras or Wailmer eggs able to be carried around?

Comment: @user867 And within the games there are characters who will measure your Pokémon (shroomish and barboach) as they're looking for particularly large ones, though the Pokédex entry remains the same.

Comment: @Samthere Yeah, I don't really find this answer persuasive. Still, I can't find any evidence to disprove it, either.